# Convert NOT IN to NOT EXISTS SQL firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

I want to convert this not in query to not exists.

```
SELECT * FROM MYCARD T1
WHERE T1.IDMONEY = 5 AND T1.IDCARD = 80
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT IDCARD, YEAR, MONEY 
    FROM MYCARD T2
    WHERE T2.IDCARD = T1.IDCARD 
    AND T2.YEAR = T1.YEAR
    AND T2.MONEY = T1.MONEY
    GROUP BY T2.IDCARD, T2.YEAR, T2.MONEY 
    HAVING COUNT(T2.IDCARD) > 1
)
AND T1.ID not in (   -- THIS NOT IN TO NOT EXISTS
    select min(ID)
    from MYCARD
    WHERE IDMONEY = 5
    AND IDCARD = 80
    group by IDCARD, YEAR
)
```

I want to get values that have ID different that min(ID). This not in works good but I need more optimized query. I tried to use something like this but It seems to be correct but It's not optimized:

```
AND EXISTS (
    select min(ID)
    from MYCARD
    WHERE IDMONEY = 5
    AND IDCARD = 80
    group by IDCARD, YEAR
    HAVING T1.ID = MIN(ID)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If using `not exists` twice is OK, you can do the following:

```
select * 
from MYCARD T1
where not exists 
(
 select 1 
 from MYCARD T2
 where ID = T1.ID and IDMONEY = 5 AND IDCARD = 80 and not exists 
 (
   select 1 
   from MYCARD 
   where IDMONEY = 5 AND IDCARD = 80 and ID < T2.ID)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly `NOT EXISTS`, but `EXISTS` :

---

```
        -- The original query  selects the values that
        -- don't have the *minimum* value per {idcard,idmony}.
        -- NOT the minimum := a lower value exists
        -- --------------------------------------------------
SELECT * 
FROM mycard t1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT *
    FROM mycard x
    WHERE x.idmoney = t1.idmoney
    AND x.idcard = t1.idcard
    AND x.id < t1.id -- a lower value exists
    )
AND t1.idmoney = 5
AND t1.idcard = 80
        ;
```

Comment: [please don't change the question. people already have answered the old version of the question] You can do a similar thing for the `COUNT(*)` subquery. if count() > 1, there must be a record with `x.id > t1.id AND the_same_matching_fields`.

Comment: I had to add some more details, question is the same. I don't know what do you mean, could you edit your answer?

Answer (score -2):

```
select * from MYCARD T1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
select 1 from MYCARD WHERE IDMONEY = 5
AND IDCARD = 80
group by IDCARD, YEAR)
```

Comment: It returns different rows that not in. Can I add something like HAVING T1.ID = min(ID) ??

Comment: That doesn't produce the right result, because it is not correlated.